# Delimiters Option for WEKA WordTokenizer

Tags: weka

I'm trying to set options for `StringToWordVector` filter using `WordTokenizer`. Here's my code:

```
StringToWordVector filter = new StringToWordVector();

//Tokenizer option (letter only)
String tokenizerOption[] = new String[2];
tokenizerOption[0] = "-tokenizer";
tokenizerOption[1] = "weka.core.tokenizers.WordTokenizer -delimiters \r\t\n .,;:\'\"()?!-><#$%&*+/@^_=[]{}|\\`~0123456789";
filter.setOptions(tokenizerOption);
filter.setInputFormat(data);
```

Then I save filtered instances to ARFF. I get this ARFF:

```
@attribute '\n' numeric
@attribute ' ' numeric
@attribute ' a ' numeric
```

As you can see, `\n` and space is not included in the delimiters. How to get it includes them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer, please see my code below:

```
//Make a filter
StringToWordVector filter = new StringToWordVector();

//Make a tokenizer
WordTokenizer wt = new WordTokenizer();
String delimiters = " \r\t\n.,;:\'\"()?!-><#$\\%&*+/@^_=[]{}|`~0123456789";
wt.setDelimiters(delimiters);
filter.setTokenizer(wt);

//Inform filter about dataset
filter.setInputFormat(data);
```